# Get posts not in array OR with specific meta_key in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem :)
I have a meta_key 'glowna'. this is checkbox. If I check this it means that post should be shown on main page of category. Also I want to show all posts that have more votes than i.ex. 10. I have code like this now:

Main page:
//posts waiting

```
$array = $wpdb->get_results("select post_id from $table where (user_recc_plus + visitor_recc_plus < 10)");
```

in $array I have only Ids

Then I have:

```
    $args=array(
'post__not_in' => $array,
'cat'=>$catId,
'order'=>'desc'
);
```

Also when I want to display waiting posts I use:

```
$args=array(
'post__in' => $array,
'cat'=>$catId,
'order'=>'desc'
);
```

It is working very good. How can I add condition that if post is in $array but has meta_key glowna checked it should be shown. For waiting posts I create:

```
$args=array(
'post__in' => $array,
'cat'=>$catId,
'meta_key'=>'glowna',
'meta_value'=>'glowna',
'meta_compare'=>'NOT LIKE',
'order'=>'desc'
);
```

and it seems to be working

But what about posts on main page of category? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it like this:

Get all post that has not enought votes:

```
$posty_poczekalnia = $wpdb->get_results("select post_id from $tabela where (user_recc_plus + visitor_recc_plus < 1)");
```

Get all posts that are checked as to be shown on main

```
$args = array(
        'cat'=>$katId,
        'meta_key'=>'glowna',
        'meta_value'=>'glowna',
        'meta_compare'=>'LIKE'
    );
```

use diff

```
$poczekalnia = array_diff($poczekalnia, $glowna);
```

and get this posts

```
$args=array(
'post__not_in' => $poczekalnia,
'cat'=>$katId,
'order'=>'desc',
'paged'=>$paged
);
```